# Bootstrap - Tooltip is not working (using bootswatch)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

does anyone have an idea why my tooltip is not working?

HTML Code:

```
<div class="form-check">
          <label class="form-check-label" >
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optionsRadios" 
            id="has-been" value="has-been" (click)='onRadioClick(2)'> Has-Been
            <i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true" 
            data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title=""></i>
          </label>

        </div>
```

My Imported bootstrap files from index.html

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/_vendor/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/flatly/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
```

Is it a problem that I am using a bootswatch theme?

**EDIT:**
Tooltips from [here](https://bootswatch.com/flatly/)

[image]

**EDIT 2:** 
I added the complete `index.html`. I am trying to change the look of my tooltips according to the picture above. At the moment I only have the default text-look.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>UniApp</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//bootswatch.com/4/flatly/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>

<body>

  <app-root></app-root>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
  </script>
<!-- 
  <script>
    $(function () {
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });  
  </script> -->


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There are so many errors in your updated bootstrap files. You're loading JS like it's a stylesheet, you're loading jQuery multiple times, Bootstrap 4 AND Bootstrap 3.  Your order of includes is wrong (jQuery then Popper then Bootstrap 4)

Comment: Thank you for your Feedback. I am new to Web programming and bootstrap could you Show me how to fix These errors??

Answer (score 3):

So for the first step we're going to need to clean up your code.  You're loading Bootstrap 3 and Bootstrap 4 and you're going to have to pick *one*.  You're also loading jQuery and Popper multiple times and your order of includes is incorrect.

If we clean up your code to support just Bootstrap 4 and order things according to their documentation you get the following code:

```js
$(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//bootswatch.com/4/flatly/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="form-check">
  <label class="form-check-label" >
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optionsRadios" id="has-been" value="has-been" (click)='onRadioClick(2)'>
    Has-Been
    <i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Test"></i>
  </label>
</div>
```

Note: The only reason this is trigging a tooltip right now is because there is an actual value in `title`.  In your presented code `title` was blank so the tooltip was never firing.

Bootswatch doesn't seem to actually affect the look of the `tooltip` component at all, at least not the Flatly theme that you're using.

Comment: hey Robert, i am really thankful for your answer I am new to bootstrap so I am learning every day.
I followed your instructions and cleaned up my code according to your answer. Though I am getting the default tooltip look..
Note: I inserted the bootstrap code in the body of my `index.html`. Is this correct?

Comment: @Stelios - Make sure you're wrapping the tooltip initialization in a `<script></script>` tag.

Comment: yes I did! I moved to the `head` of the `index.html` and i have the same problem...

Comment: by the way I am programming in typescript/angular 4

Comment: do you have an idea what else I can try?

Comment: Are you viewing `index.html` locally (ex: `file://`).  If so the omission of `https:` could be causing the script includes to not process.  Normally though you would place all your JS at the bottom of the document, not the top.

Comment: Hi Robert, thank you but none of these worked for me. I just posted the current status of my `index.html` and i hope someone has an idea...

Comment: @Stelios - In your updated `index.html` you aren't loading Popper.js.  This is required for tooltip positioning in Bootstrap 4.  Compare the `<script>` being loaded in my code vs. your own.  Popper needs to be included after jQuery and before Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
    });  
</script>
```

and enter sth to title

btw, you use bootstrap 4 css and bootstrap 3 js

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/flatly/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: hey thank you it's working. I am using as mentioned a bootswatch theme  and i would like to use their tooltips not the default one. I uploaded a picture to my question. Do you have an idea how use bootswatch tooltips.